# How come this very simple code produces a segmentation fault?

Tags: arrays, memory

When I compile the following code using `gcc test.c -o test` and then run `test`, I get a `Segmentation fault: 11` message:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double xs[600000];
    double ys[600000];

    return 0;
}
```

What is going on? If I remove the `ys` declaration, then it works, and if I make the array size smaller (eg. 500000), then it works. I am stumped.

Comment: Because you are running out of stack space

Comment: Ok, yes, thank you. But I am very surprised that I run out of memory so fast. A double is 8 bytes, so I'm only trying to allocate about 10Mb of memory here. Surely my modern computer can do that. I thought I had 8Gb of RAM.

Comment: stack is not infinite; in the linux & windows word, default stack size is 1-2 Mb
You are trying to put more than 9 Mb on the stack, so the error

Comment: You are not running out of memory. `xs` and `ys` are automatic variables and therefore are allocated on the stack. You are overflowing the stack.

Comment: @BruceBartlett, your are not running out of memory, you are running out of the memory reserved for the stack. try to allocate on the heap the same amount of bytes (`double[] xs = new double[600000]`), you will have no problem doing that

Comment: Ok thank you. One last question - if I try to debug by putting in a printf("Executed this line.\n") before the line which causes the stack overflow, then the printf actually doesn't execute. That is kind of spooky - what order are things executed in?